# adding a small value to only the diagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-inverse, diagonal

I am a newbie to matlab and I am trying to find out the inverse of matrix with very small values. When i try to find the inverse I get an error saying that the matrix is singular. One of the solutions suggested is to try and add some elements to the diagonal elements. I know i have to use eye and diag methods but I am not able come up the correct soltion.

Any comments will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at [singular value decompostion](http://www.kwon3d.com/theory/jkinem/svd.html)

Comment: @Mauro, I have tried SVD and unfortunately for this is get an out of Memory error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to add the identity matrix or a multiple of it to your *square* matrix, you can do

```
A_new = A_old + k*eye(size(A_old));
```

where `A_old` is your matrix and `k` is some multiplier. If you want to add a different values to each diagonal element, you can do something like

```
A_new = A_old + diag(values);
```

where `values` is a vector with as many number of elements as the number of columns (or rows) of your matrix `A_old`.

If your matrix is large, it will be more memory efficient to use `spdiags` as:

```
dim_A = size(A_old,1);
A_new = A_old + spdiags(values(:),0,dim_A,dim_A);
```

or use linear indexing like in Amro's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a square matrix, you can add to the diagonal as:

```
[r,~] = size(M);
M(1:r+1:end) = M(1:r+1:end) + values;
```

where `values` can be scalar or a vector of `r` elements