# How to add one to each entry of the diagonal [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I have a matrix such as

```
[1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1]
```

I want it to be

```
[2     1     1
 1     2     1
 1     1     2]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8016443/97160

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [***`eye`***](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) function to get an identity matrix and add to original matrix

```
result = A+eye(3,3) ; % A the original matrix
```

Comment: Of course if you want to add something to the diagonal of `A`, one would like to use `eye(size(A))`. This also works for nonsquare matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility, which requires less operations (may be better for large matrices):

```
A(1:size(A,1)+1:end) = A(1:size(A,1)+1:end) + 1;
```

This uses the concept of [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to address the diagonal elements.

Comment: If you need the result to be a new matrix this one seems to be a little faster, but if you don't mind updating the existing one this really is much faster (for `A=rand(5000)`). -- For others who don't get the code at first sight: The indexing is of form `start:step:end`, and not `vector1+vector2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way via logical indexing:

```
idx = eye(size(A))>0;
A(idx)= A(idx)+1;
```

This can easily be used for other things as well:

```
A(~idx)=2*A(~idx); %Multiply all non diagonal elements by two
A(eye(size(A))>0)=1:min(size(A)); %Set the diagonal to 1:n
```

Comment: Note that for the simple case, this method seems to be slowest.